# AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights - replace string function in queries on Auth0 Event Types

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm streaming the Auth0 logs to the CloudWatch log group and now I would like to query the logs for occurrences of each of the [Log Event Type Codes](https://auth0.com/docs/deploy-monitor/logs/log-event-type-codes).

The type is in the field: `detail.data.type` as in this example:

```
Field               Value
---------------------------------------------------------
@ingestionTime      1684845468149
@logStream          f802329f-3cf2-3378-91a1-9f3ed9dfca20
@message            {"version":"0","id": ...}
@timestamp          1684845467000
detail-type         Auth0 log
detail.data.ip      11.22.33.444
detail.data.log_id  90022
detail.data.type    seacft
```

Currently, I'm running this query to count occurrences of each Log event type:

```
fields @timestamp, detail.data.type
| stats count(detail.data.type) as occurrence_count by detail.data.type
```

Which produces a bit unclear result:

```
    detail.data.type occurrence_count
1   ssa              4
2   seacft           5
3   s                2
4   scp              1
5   scpr             1
6   fp               1
7   fcpr             1
8   fu               2
```

What I want to do is to replace the enigmatic `ssa` `s` `fp` with the corresponding `Success Silent Auth` `Success Login` `Failed Login (Incorrect Password)`

```
   Event Type                 occurrence_count
    1   Success Silent Auth              4
    3   Success Login                    2
    6   Failed Login (Password)          1
```

Can it be done with replace()?

Answer (score 1):

Facing same question. A bit hard to imagine that it is so hard to do, considering the obvious need. So, the proposed solution looks a bit ugly, feel free to suggest a better one.

Anyways, the working solution I've come up with so far is (lets limit to 2 values for clarity):

```
fields @timestamp 
| filter detail.data.type = "f" OR detail.data.type = "s"
| fields replace(detail.data.type, "s", "|Success|") as text_s
| fields replace(detail.data.type, "f", "|Failure|") as text_f
| fields concat(text_s, text_f) as text_combined
| parse text_combined "|*|" as text
| stats count() as rCount by text
| sort by rCount desc
```

Thing is that replace could be used to create a new field. So, I create x amount of new fields dedicated to each code with a special characters around the string. Then I concat them into a single string and parse the desired description out.

It is pretty ugly so I hope that my filter in the beginning does actually filter the entries I am not interested in, and not applying this code to every entry.